# ¿Cómo puedo tener varios interpretes de Python en VSCode?

Tags: python, vscode

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de Django con python 3.9 y algunas líneas de código me salen con error, pero sé que están bien y es solo cuestión de poner un interprete con alguna versión de python menor a la que tengo. Sin embargo, a la hora de intentar cambiar el interprete solo me sale este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quisiera que me saliera algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Saben cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Comienza siempre por revisar la documentación. [Normalmente](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter) te va a resolver estas dudas.

Answer (score 2):

La extensión de Python para VScode, según la [documentación oficial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter), busca entornos de Python en los siguientes lugares:

> - Rutas estándar de instalación de Python como /usr/local/bin, /usr/sbin, /sbin, c:\python27, c:\python36, etc.
> - Entornos virtuales directamente bajo la carpeta raíz del workspace (proyecto).
> - Entornos virtuales en el folder al que apunta la variable de configuración `python.venvPath` (revise `General settings`), que puede contener múltiples entornos virtuales. La extensión busca entornos virtuales en las subcarpetas de primer nivel dentro de este directorio.
> - Entornos virtuales en un directorio `~/.virtualenvs` para virtualenvwrapper.
> - Intérpretes instalados por pyenv.
> - Entornos virtuales en la ruta identificada por la variable de entorno WORKON_HOME (usada por virtualenvwrapper).
> - Entornos Conda que contengan intérprete Python. VS Code no muestra entornos Conda que no contengan el intérprete Python.
> - Intérpretes instalados en un directorio `.direnv` para direnv bajo la raíz del workspace (proyecto).

También pueden [añadirse entornos](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter) que no detecte automáticamente (de la lista) y añadir/editar el elemento `python.pythonPath`